# HttpRequestMessage is null in HttpClientHandler.ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback

Tags: c#, .net, dotnet-httpclient

I am attempting to use the [`ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclienthandler.servercertificatecustomvalidationcallback?view=netframework-4.7.1) of `HttpClientHandler` but the value of the request parameter is always null.  Is this expected behavior or do I need to set a bit somewhere?

For example the following snippet results in printing Request not defined 4 times.

```
var handler = new HttpClientHandler();
handler.ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback = (_request,_certificate, _chain,_errors) => 
{
    Console.WriteLine(_request?.RequestUri.ToString() ?? "Request not defined");
    return true;
};

var client = new HttpClient(handler);
var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, "https://google.com");
client.SendAsync(request);
client.GetAsync("https://google.com");
```

Comment: Yes it seems by design. Not sure why though.